# Failed to use VBA capturing the web table

Tags: excel, vba, html-table, msxml

I would like to capture the table showing [here](http://mis.twse.com.tw/stock/fibest.jsp?stock=2402&lang=zh_tw)

But the number in the web table shows up to be "-" in my Excel file.

Here is the VBA scripts that I wrote for capturing the table in the middle:

```
Sub data()

    Dim xmlHttp As Object
    Dim TR_col As Object, TR As Object
    Dim TD_col As Object, TD As Object
    Dim row As Long, col As Long

    Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    xmlHttp.Open "GET", "http://mis.twse.com.tw/stock/fibest.jsp?stock=29151&lang=zh_tw", False
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8"
    xmlHttp.send

    Dim html As Object
    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText

    Dim tbl As Object
    Set tbl = html.getElementById("hor-minimalist-tb")

    row = 1
    col = 1

    Set TR_col = html.getElementsByTagName("TR")
    For Each TR In TR_col
        Set TD_col = TR.getElementsByTagName("TD")
        For Each TD In TD_col
            Cells(row, col) = TD.innerText
            col = col + 1
        Next
        col = 1
        row = row + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: None of that looks like Javascript to me.

Comment: @Jeeped I think the OP was confusing the HTML DOM functions of MSXML with JavaScript - I removed the tag.

Comment: As far as I can tell that code will fill up a bunch of cells. is every cell a "-"? I suggest you at least step through your code to try troubleshooting. Is `tbl` populated as expected?

Answer (score 0):

The table is slow to load. XHR is too fast. Swop to Selenium or Internet Explorer where you can take advantage of waits.

Here is an example of using IE to scrape the table including using a wait to ensure over the scheduled 5s refresh time. I have used the English version of site:

---

**Image on web:**

[image: Web]

---

**Output from code:**

[image: Code output]

---

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub MakeSelectionGetData()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    Const url = "http://mis.twse.com.tw/stock/fibest.jsp?stock=2402&lang=en_us"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate url

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 6)

        Dim nTable As HTMLTable
        Set nTable = .document.getElementById("hor-minimalist-tb")
        Dim Headers()
        Headers = Array("Best Bid Volume", "Best Bid Price", "Best Ask Price", "Best Ask Volume")
        Dim TR As Object, TD As Object, r As Long, c As Long

        With ActiveSheet
            r = 2
            c = 1
            Dim TR_col As Object, TD_col As Object
            Set TR_col = nTable.getElementsByTagName("TR")
            .Range("A1").Resize(1, UBound(Headers) + 1) = Headers
            For Each TR In TR_col
                Set TD_col = TR.getElementsByTagName("TD")
                For Each TD In TD_col
                    .Cells(r, c) = TD.innerText
                    c = c + 1
                Next
                c = 1
                r = r + 1
            Next
        End With
        .Quit
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```